# Background Intelligent Transfer Service(BITS) download speed really slow?

Tags: c#, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I am using BITS 2.1 version, on Window XP SP3.
I have 2 files, to download using BITS, one is around 9 Mb, other around 1 Mb. I created a BITS job in my C# code, added the 2 files to this Job and started the download. The job has a priority of Normal. The 9Mb file gets downloaded quickly but the other file does not start downloading for a loooong time (around 20 min!). If the Job priority is made to Foreground, both downloads happen in like 3-4 seconds.

Does anyone have any clue why BITS behaves like this. 20 minutes seems to be really long for such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You answered it in your blog, but never came back to post your results

http://theraneman.blogspot.com/2010/07/is-your-background-intelligent-transfer.html

> BITS uses Round Robin algorithm within a queue of jobs of same
>   priority. Thus having just 1 file improves the situation for BITS.
>
> If you are responsible for building a tool which uses BITS to download
>   stuff from a server on client machines, and you do not have control
>   over the network policies and all that, at least try to zip all the
>   files into 1 and download it. It surely improves the speed. If you are
>   allowed to change the priorities of jobs, give an option to the user
>   saying something like “Download Now”, which would change the Job
>   priority to Foreground and things would come blazingly fast on the
>   machine.

Comment: This actually doesn't explain anything.  Why would a round robin algorithm cause that level of discrepancy?  There's something else going on.